# removing invalid characters in xml with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

In an XML-file I am seeing this in the source: 
`&lt;#&gt;` which causes problems in another application which sees this as <#>

I am using XSLT2.0 and I have tried to do a replace on anything from # to div to remove the `&lt;#&gt;` with an empty string altogether. 
I have done this by putting the structure inside a variable and replacing.

The result of the replace function is that I am loosing all other elements as well.
Any suggestions are welcome. 
The input could look something like this:

```
`<html>
 <body>
   <p>&lt;#&gt;This is just a test</p>
 </body>
</html>`
```

But it can also look something like this:

```
`<html>
 <body>
   &lt;#&gt;<p>This is just a test</p>
 </body>
</html>`
```

Wanted out put is:

```
`<html>
 <body>
   <p>This is just a test</p>
 </body>
</html>`
```

The XSL I have tried is this, which removes all elements. I do see I am doing this on a copy-of, so that' might be wrong...:

```
`<xsl:template name="body">
  <xsl:copy-of select="replace($bodycontent, '#', 'div /')" />
 </xsl:template name="body">

   <xsl:variable name="bodycontent">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/newsMessage/itemSet/newsItem/contentSet/inlineXML/h:html/h:body/h:section/h:p" />
    <p class="txt-ind">
        <xsl:value-of select="//rightsInfo/copyrightHolder/name" />
    </p>
</xsl:variable>`
```

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you have currently tried? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&lt;#&gt;', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

then any occurrence of those characters will be removed, online at http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQfu

Comment: that solved it, and also adding the replace on some other elements. But the last one solved those combinations that were outside some elements.